# Reading and enconding(b64) pdf files in python

Tags: python, pdf, encoding, base64

I'm trying to open a pdf file in binary and encode it in base64("utf-8"), but I'm getting this ERROR message:

**AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'b64encode'**

I'm working in windows 10 and python 3, code:

```
attach_file_name = os.getcwd() + '\doc.pdf'
attach_file = open(attach_file_name, "rb")
attach_file = attach_file.b64encode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `base64` module.

```
import base64

with open(pod, 'rb') as pdf:
    encoded = base64.b64encode(pdf.read())
```